# Regex - match until a group of multiple possibilities

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following text:
**You may have that thing NO you dont BUT maybe yes**

I'm trying to write a regex which can match everything until it finds some specific words, **"NO"** and **"BUT"** in this example, and if the string has both of the words, then stop at the first one:

**You may have that thing *NO* you dont BUT maybe yes**
*You may have that thing*

**You may have that thing you dont *BUT* maybe yes**
*You may have that thing you dont*

I was trying the regex below, but the problem is that it stops at **BUT** even when it has **NO**:

```
(.*)(?:NO|BUT)
```

Match example of the above regex, in bold being the full match and in italic being group 1:
***You may have that thing NO you dont* BUT** maybe yes

What i expect:
***You may have that thing* NO** you dont BUT maybe yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us fix your regex pattern

```
^(.*?)\s*(?:NO|BUT)
```

Now we can use the above `regex` pattern with `search`

```
s = 'You may have that thing NO you dont BUT maybe yes'
match = re.search(r'^(.*?)\s*(?:NO|BUT)', s)
```

---

```
>>> match.group(1)
'You may have that thing'
```

**Regex details:**

- `^` : Assert position at the start of line
- `(.*?)` : First capturing group

  - `.*?` : Matches any character zero or more times but as few times as possible
- `\s*` : Zero or more whitespace characters
- `(?:NO|BUT)` : Non capturing group

  - `NO|BUT` : Matches one of `NO`, `BUT`

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/YcciAy/1)

Comment: That's a good explanation, very clear, thank you!!